# Clonezilla not able to mount drive?

Tags: hard-drive, clonezilla

I have a machine where I want to create a clone of the primary disk and save it on a secondary (internal) disk. After a little reading, I decided to try Clonezilla Live, but I'm running into the strangest error and have no idea why.

1. After starting up and choosing the keymap and the like, I choose "device-image" to save an image of a drive.
2. I then choose "local-dev", since I want to use an internal device.
3. It prompts me to plug in any USB devices and press Enter. I just press Enter since I don't want to use this.
4. Clonezilla informs me I need to choose a disk to mount as /home/parimag. I'm presented with 2 disks to choose from. One is the disk I want to clone (sdb1 with an NTFS partition), and the other is where I want to save the image (sda5 with a FAT32 partition). (Please don't ask why the drives are assigned those letters and numbers. This machine was given to me like that.)
5. I choose sda5, the FAT drive.
6. I'm prompted to choose a directory for the Clonezilla image. I'm only presented with "/ Top_directory_in_the_local_device", so I press Enter to select it.
7. I then see the following error:

`Clonezilla image home directory /home/partimag is not a mounting point! Failed to mount other device as /home/partimag!`

I'm then given the option to continue anyway, but I don't know what will happen if I do. This doesn't really give me much information about what the problem is. I would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so I tried to to mount it manually in shell

```
mount -t auto /dev/sda5 /home/partimag
```

But then I got error about device being in RAID. I gave up with clonezilla and used dd instead.

Comment: I gave up on Clonezilla, too. I'll try to see what product it was I ended up using later, but it wasn't `dd` directly.

Comment: This is probably extremely late, but maybe it will help future Googlers. I ended up using [Redo](http://redobackup.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still a relevant question... But I don't believe you can save ntfs to fat32. You might consider formatting the drive to be ntfs and try again. I don't believe this was a clonezilla issue. It was you trying to save a partition to a different style partition. But, I'm relatively new to this so I could be wrong.

Comment: As I recall, what I was *trying* to do was save an image as a file on the fat32 drive. It's entirely possible that I was doing so incorrectly, though. This was so long ago that I can't recall the details off-hand.